# Electric Power and Energy

Tags: energy, electricity, power

I was asked a question three times this week and I have been giving the same explanation over and over again, but I am starting to question myself.

if you have data on a PV panel production in the following form:
every 15min I have an instantaneous reading, so let's say that between 10am and 11:30am (1.5h) I had the following readings:

| hour | reading |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 0.50 kW |
| 10:15 | 0.75 kW |
| 10:30 | 0.75 kW |
| 10:45 | 0.50 kW |
| 11:00 | 1.00 kW |
| 11:15 | 0.75 kW |
| 11:30 | 1.25 kW |

What would be the total energy produced? and total power?
I am struggling to grasp the concept of measuring energy power at a specific time step, or measuring kWh every 30 min for example, if energy is power x time, how can I measure energy at a 30 min interval and how should I aggragate it for a day?

thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Total power produced is not a concept.  It would be like asking for "total speed" of a car.  You don't total rates.  You could have an average speed over a period of time, but not a total.

You can total energy, but only by making assumptions about what's happening during the times you didn't record the instantaneous power.  If the power changes, the total energy changes, but you might not notice.

Power multiplied by time is energy.  So if the readings you have are representative of that 15 minute period, you can approximate the total energy produced.  You'd multiply by that quarter hour.

| Time | Power | 15 min Energy | Total Energy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00 | 0.5 kW | 0.125 kWh | 0.125 kWh |
| 10:15 | 0.75 kW | 0.1875 kWh | 0.3125 kWh |
| 10:30 | 0.75 kW | 0.1875 kWh | 0.500 kWh |
| 10:45 | 0.5 kW | 0.125 kWh | 0.625 kWh |
| 11:00 | 1.0 kW | 0.250 kWh | 0.875 kWh |
| 11:15 | 0.75 kW | 0.1875 kWh | 1.0625 kWh |
| 11:30 | 1.25 kW | 0.3125 kWh | 1.375 kWh |

Of course this is like asking how far your car has gone when you just are told the speed at a few specific times.  The car needs to not change speed much for you to be able to get close.  If it stops and starts a lot, your calculations won't mean anything.

Comment: Probably the only one I did in my head.